# div to flip when scrolling left/right horizontally

Tags: jquery, html, css, effects

I am trying to replicate the effect which can be seen on this website http://www.toolofna.com/#!/work. When scrolling left/right horizontally, the div's inside which there are different images flip about the x-axis and then settle down to their original position. I know that this can be achieved using CSS3 but I presume that there's some jQuery code also running behind this effect.

I tried searching regarding this on the internet and came across webkit-transform-origin but I guess that this effect is something more complicated. Looking forward to a solution.

Comment: Here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/GDdtS/6240/ so instead of using :hover in css you can use jQuery events to flip it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/GDdtS/6241/ (click to flip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bts3a/) won't take into account the initial state of the cards (you can do that on your own if you like), it has managed to achieve the *onScroll* effect you were looking for.

```
var visibleXStart = $('#wrapper').offset().left;
var visibleXEnd = $('#wrapper').offset().left + $('#wrapper').width();

$('#wrapper').scroll(function () {
    $('.card').each(function () {
        var thisCard = $(this);
        if (thisCard.offset().left < visibleXEnd - 100) thisCard.css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotatey(0deg)'
        });
        else thisCard.css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotatey(-180deg)'
        });
    });
});
```

I have extended the fiddle provided by @aamir-afridi

You might also want to do some cleanup of the code to suit your webpage.

Hope it helps.